# If I click on the svn upgrade working copy from svn than what is the impact of that in my working space

Tags: svn

Before some time I was switch my branch of doscms folder.After that when I was right click on the doscms folder it doesn't show the SVN Update and SVN Commit ,infect it show the SVN Upgrate Working copy.So can you please tell me that if I click on the SVN Upgrate Working copy then what type of impact it will show in my doscms folder.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to check [the related Apache Subversion 1.7 Release Notes entry](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#wc-upgrade):

> Subversion 1.7 introduces substantial changes to the working copy
>   format. In previous releases of Subversion, Subversion would
>   automatically update the working copy to the new format when a write
>   operation was performed. Subversion 1.7, however, will make this a
>   manual step. Before using Subversion 1.7 with their working copies,
>   users will be required to run a new command, svn upgrade to update the
>   metadata to the new format. This command may take a while, and for
>   some users, it may be more practical to simply checkout a new working
>   copy.

*Please note that you can't use the upgraded working copy with older clients (e.g. SVN 1.6 and older).*